# use-package: load all defined packages

Tags: use-package, load

I use `use-package` to defer package loading.
This is useful in emacs standalone mode.
I additional run emacs in daemon mode (`emacs --daemon`), then this behavior is not desired.

**Is there a way to load all, in my init files defined, packages?**
In a way like this:

```
(if (daemonp)
    (foo-for-all-till-now-known-definitions-load-package))
```

*Notes:*
My init file is distributed over multiple files and directories.

I do not want to keep an extra list of packages which I have defined using `use-package`.
Me doing this, is not wanted:

```
(if (daemonp)
    (require 'org)
    (require 'paredit)
    ... )
```

*Edit:* it seems, that it is not clear what should be achieved by this. So here it is more clearly:

1. Packages should be loaded on demand only , when I am using `emacs` (without daemon or server mode). This is already working by using keywords `:defer`, `:commands` and `:bind`
   **and**
2. In server mode all packages should be loaded right at start of `emacs --daemon`, so that there is no waiting time later. This I hope to achieve by triggering a function, which triggers all packages (the ones defined using `use-package`) to be loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the customization options available for `use-package`. I think you can set `use-package-always-demand` based on how Emacs was started to get the behavior you want.

For example at the start of your init file (before any use-package forms) you could do something like:

```
(setq use-package-always-demand (daemonp))
```

Comment: not the solution I expected, but this is working!  After just a little bit tweaking of all my use-package package definitions. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can either add `:ensure t` to each package you want to load from ELPA, or add `(setq use-package-always-ensure t)` to the beginning of your emacs config file and add `:ensure nil` to those few packages that you do not want from ELPA.

Packages are downloaded or upgraded at load time. When you want to install a new package, you should write the use-package sexp for it and eval it with `C-x C-e` to install and configure it at the same time.

Read mode instructions from https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#for-packageel-users

Comment: My question is not about downloading and installing, but about loading at runtime. A feature activated by `:defer t` or `:commands` or `:bind` does this -> defered loading of a package.

Comment: I do not see any reason why packages should not be deferred in daemon mode. I start my emacs and it defers most packages and enters daemon mode. I can start working with it sooner and at any point I can use emacsclient to open files into it from command line.

Comment: Emacs server (daemon) is started with operating system only once per day, I don't care how long this takes, but I do not want have long load time when using some functionality of a package, so it can/should load every package on startup. Emacs in standalone (no daemon) is used to quickly view a file which is out of context to the opened files on the daemon, so load-time matters a lot. The `:defer t` is for standalone mode, but server should have everything ready after start.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but according to the README there is a `:demand` feature that could do what you want:

> You can override package deferral with the `:demand` keyword. Thus, even if you use `:bind`, using `:demand` will force loading to occur immediately and not establish an autoload for the bound key.

Comment: Then all packages are always loaded at start. This behavior is not wanted. I edited the Question to make it more clear.

Comment: no they are not. it is a per package attribute.